# simple code, but cursor is still returning null from content provider

Tags: android, null, cursor, android-contentprovider

Got a problem here with a simple section of code that uses managedQuery cursors.  Two parts, the top half of the code puts a string into the LATITUDE column of the MediaStore database content provider.

The second part of the code below that reads that same string back from the database. This is where it is returning a null result.  Either because the string was not correctly read into the database in the first part of the code or there is an error in the second part where it reads it back from the database.

I am using the LATITUDE column of the Media.images content provider to store a string.  There is no other unused column that is available so that is why I am using it.
The goal is to put the string path name of the mp3 file into the LATITUDE column of an image and read it back out again later with another query.

I tracked down the problem to the following code. The cursor in the second part of code is returning null.  Is there something wrong with my use of cursors, or some error in this that I don't know about?

```
  String displayName; // string pathname of the mp3 file to be put into LATITUDE column
  String filename; // the pathname of the image that I want to add the database info to

  ContentValues imageValues = new ContentValues();
  String selection3 = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='" + filename +"'";
  imageValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE, displayName);
  getContentResolver().update(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
  imageValues, selection3, null);

  String[] proj6 = { MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE };
  String selection6 = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='" + filename +"'";
  Cursor cursor2 = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
  proj6, selection6, null, null);
   cursor2.moveToFirst();        
  String displayer = (String)
  cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE));
```

Comment: how much does the update returns ?

Comment: do you mean the size of the string?  it is 10 to 12 character,  pathname of an mp3 music file on the SD card

Comment: no, i mean the return value of the update method.

Comment: i just ran a Toast message to display the return value of the update method. and it is returning 0.  that is strange because i expected null, not zero

Comment: then no update was made. are you sure there is something to be updated in the first place ?

Comment: i will check that.  so it looks like the update function is working because it does not return null.  but zero means that no rows have been updated.  now i understand more about what is going on.

Comment: i wonder if there is restriction on what i can put into a content provider database column.  is it possible that the LATITUDE column only takes integers and not strings?    i thought that you could put any kind of data type in a column.

Comment: First, you could/should check return values from methods like update().  You could also look at the database to see if the value was written.  That would help identify where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that there was not an error like I thought it would be.  It was only a typing error.

put method has "Images.Media.LATITUDE"
update method has "Audio.Media.LATITUDE", changed this to "Images.Media.LATITUDE" like it is in the put method and it works now.

```
  imageValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE, displayName);
  getContentResolver().update(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
  imageValues, selection3, null);
```